First Firefox extension test not going well
I am writing a first test of a firefox extension. I am using the following websites as assistance:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items
https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/main/menu-demo/background.js
Here is my code:
mainfest.json
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "version":"1.0",
  "name":"Test",
  "content_scripts":[
    {
     "matches":["<all_urls>"],
     "js":["main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions":["contextMenus"]
}

main.js
alert("test");

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

browser.contextMenus.create(
  {
    id: "AlertTest",
    title: "Test2",
    contexts: ["all"],
  },
  onCreated,
);

alert("Test 2");

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "AlertTest":
      console.log(info.selectionText);
      alert("The test extension is up and running");
      break;
  }
});

The extension does load, but i never get to alert("Test 2");. In addition the console says "TypeError: browser.contextMenus is undefined". Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
Edit: Getting closer, but context menu addition still isn't showing up. Current code...
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "Test",
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}

background.js
function onError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

browser.contextMenus.create(
  {
    id: "AlertTest",
    title: "Test2",
    contexts: ["all"],
  },
  onCreated,
);

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "AlertTest":
      console.log(info.selectionText);
      break;
  }
});

Thanks once again for any help.

Does it work if you upgrade to manifest v3?

I don't know what the difference is, but i tried "manifest_version":3, and now the extension doesn't load at all. Switching back to 2 and i at least get the alert. If it helps at all, i have the extension loaded as temporary, in Firefox 115.

Of course you don't get the second alert, since the error stops the script before that. I'm not sure why you're getting that error, since it looks exactly like the sample code in the Firefox extension documentation.

right, thats my point. the browser.contextMenus item is undefined. However, the tutorials i list use this command and say it will work.
... I think i saw somewhere that said you can only add a context menu in a content based JS, and not from an extension, but that doesnt explain at all these tutorials which say i can do this.

I think this needs to be a background script, not a content script. See the example here

Hold please, modifying my scripts based on your suggestion......

... I have now added it as a background script instead, using your sample json file. Now it does load, it does open up a console on loading too now, with no big error, but i don't get to the first alert and the menu item does not load either, and i see no error in the console related to my script.

If you copy the sample extension I linked to, does it work for you?

Sorry, i had a few issues downloading the content to local. This script DOES work when loaded.

I recommend you use console.log() rather than alert() for debugging. Maybe background scripts aren't allowed to alert.

I wondered about that also. I removed that from my scripts before you recommended such. Should i update my main post to reflect current code?

If the current code still doesn't work, updated the question with it. I'm not a FF programmer so I don't think I'll be able to help further.

The main error has been that the script needs to be in the background, not run as a content script, as suggested by Barmar and erosman.
The secondary issue is that "onCreated" is not recognized when creating a context menu item. I replaced that with something from an example that Barmar provided, and I don't QUITE understand what the thing that replaces it does. It seems to be catching an error and sending it somewhere. The code is now working though, as seen below:
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Tests adding a context menu item.",
    "version": "1.0",
    
    
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}

background.js
console.log("Start");

browser.contextMenus.create(
    {
        id: "AlertTest",
        title: "Test2",
        contexts: ["all"],
    },
    () => void browser.runtime.lastError,
);

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "AlertTest":
        console.log(info.selectionText);
        break;
    }
});

function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}


Ypu don't need onCreated or the () => void browser.runtime.lastError at all. You dont need onError either, as it wont be called. info.selectionText would only show if there is a selection.

Content scripts WebExtension APIs are limited.
browser.contextMenus is not available in the "content_scripts". It should be created and listened to in the background script.
For example:
mainfest.json
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "version":"1.0",
  "name":"Test",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  },
  "permissions":["contextMenus"]
}

Note: alert() is not available in the background script. Use console.log() instead.

Both points you have made have been noted. I have edited my main post to reflect most recent changes. As of yet, I still can't get the context menu to appear, and am still working to see what is wrong. As a note, i added a console.log to the very start of the background script and am not seeing that in console, so it looks like the script isn't being loaded at all.

Sorry, the above information is partly incorrect. I have found that at least in firefox, when you move a script from a content script to a background script, the output gets moved to a different console.
Content script: Right click anywhere on any webpage -> Inspect -> Click console
Background script: navigate to about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox -> find your extension and click "Inspect".
Just learning the ropes here! :)
